# can't resolve all parameters for [object OBJECT], after ionic serve

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

not sure what I'm doing wrong, but when trying to use ionic and Cordova plugins I receive the following error after ionic serve: "can't resolve all parameters for [object OBJECT],[object OBJECT],[object OBJECT],[object OBJECT],[object OBJECT],?"

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { Diagnostic } from '@ionic-native/diagnostic';
import { CameraPreview, CameraPreviewOptions, CameraPreviewDimensions} from '@ionic-native/camera-preview';
declare var cordova: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [CameraPreview, Diagnostic]
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    public file:File,
    public diagnostic:Diagnostic,
    public cameraPreview: CameraPreview,
    public previewRect: CameraPreviewOptions
    ) {
    this.checkPermissions();
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

I got the same issue somewhere, so I removed the last parameter of constructor and given it before constructor. In your case like this,

```
export class HomePage {

 public previewRect: CameraPreviewOptions;

 constructor(
  public navCtrl: NavController,
  public toastCtrl: ToastController,
  public file:File,
  public diagnostic:Diagnostic,
  public cameraPreview: CameraPreview   
 ) {
  this.checkPermissions();
 }
}
```

I don't know if this is the right solution but resolved my issue.

Comment: No, This can only let go the compiler issue but will fail during run time what we would expect is object of specified class which is created during run time when the constructor is called

Answer (score 3):

This is a less known angular dependency issue, where compiler is unable to untangle the dependency tree.

The solution is to use `@Inject` with declarations.

```js
export class HomePage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    public file:File,
    public diagnostic:Diagnostic,
    @Inject(CameraPreview) public cameraPreview: CameraPreview   
  ) {
    this.checkPermissions();
  }
}
```

With this you are saying to compiler that missing class will be injected at later point.

Also, important is to say that `CameraPreview` itself should be decorated with `@Injectable()`.

```js
@Injectable()
export class CameraPreview
  // ... your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! @Inject() made my app working, was searching for more than an hour!

Comment: @GauravGupta, glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your ionic application may clear this issue if everything is imported as expected